# Xamarin Forms: prevent automatic scrolling on Entry Focus

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, scroll, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin Forms (4.5.0.617) for a cross platform project.
I would like to prevent the automatic scroll of the parent ScrollView when an Entry obtains focus.

Is there any property or method I could use to avoid automatic scrolling?

Comment: Could you attach the code ? I tried this but can't reproduce your issue .

Comment: Just include an Entry inside a ScrollView. You can nest it in some other VisualElement like a StackLayout to make it appear at the bottom of it. When you tap on the Entry you will notice that the ScrollView will automatically scroll to the position the Entry is. It is the default behavior of Xamarin Foms

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin improves the feature since people don't want to overlap the entry while keyboard shows up , you can find a lot of threads which discuss the issue

[Keyboard overlaps Editor in Xamarin.Forms on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53078705/keyboard-overlaps-editor-in-xamarin-forms-on-ios)

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/151812/ios-keyboard-overlapping-entry

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27383/keyboard-hides-input-in-xamarin-forms

#### Update

You can create custom renderer , disable the scroll when entry get focus ,enable the scroll when lose focus .

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace App2.iOS
{
    class MyRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (this.Control != null)
            {
                Control.Started += Control_Started;
                Control.Ended += Control_Ended;
            }
        }

        private void Control_Ended(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var s = Control.Superview.Superview.Superview;
            if (s != null && s is UIScrollView)
            {
                var ss = s as UIScrollView;
                ss.ScrollEnabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void Control_Started(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var s = Control.Superview.Superview.Superview;
            if(s != null && s is UIScrollView)
            {
                var ss = s as UIScrollView;
                ss.ScrollEnabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Because I need to do something custom, which does not require the default standard functionality

Comment: I need the scroll to be enabled, because I want to perform a scrollTo customized. I just need to prevent the automatic scroll when the Entry is focused